# Javascript date array, filling in missing days incrementaly

Tags: javascript, date, flot

I'm trying to display a graph with Flot. My data array does not have a date set if there is no value for that date. I've followed the accepted answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14522667/how-to-configure-flot-to-draw-missing-time-series-on-y-axis-at-point-zero) to 'fill in the gaps', but I now want the value to be the last value, and not 0. I can't get my head around how to get the previous date's value. I've tried getting the previous value with `var previousTotal = date[i][1];`, but I can't seem to get the right part of the array no matter what I try.

Can anyone help please?

```
function fillInGapsAdding(data) {
      var startDay = data[0][0],
        newData = [data[0]];


        // Loop through all items in array
      for (i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
        var diff = dateDiff(data[i - 1][0], data[i][0]);
        var startDate = new Date(data[i - 1][0]);
        if (diff > 1) 
        {
          for (j = 0; j < diff - 1; j++) 
          {
            var fillDate = new Date(startDate).setDate(startDate.getDate() + (j + 1));
            var previousTotal = date[i][1];
              newData.push([fillDate, 0]);
          }
        }
        newData.push(data[i]);
      }
      return newData;
    }
```

Comment: You can use `var previousTotal = date[i][j - 1];`

Comment: Sorry didn't work, put it pointed me in the right direction to figure it out :)

Answer (score 0):

After a bit more work, I figured it out....
`var previousTotal = data[i][1];`